# Simply joining two vectors by MatLab

Tags: matlab

I simply want to create output by applying A and using B as index. For example,

```
A = [7;9]
B = [0;0;1;1;2]

output = [0;0;7;7;9]
```

Because

0th of A is considered as 0,

1st of A is 7,

2nd of A is 9.

I tried to use `accumarray` but this function is quite hard to understand and I don't know how to apply this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "0th of A is considered as 0"

No, in MatLab it's not. Indices are always positive integer. Hence you need to translate `A` to add one more column for 0 and increment `B` for proper index values.

```
A = [7;9];
B = [0;0;1;1;2];

A = [0;A];
A(B+1)
```

Output

```
ans =

   0
   0
   7
   7
   9
```

Comment: I am surprised because as far as I remember this (or something that is similar with this which is actually wrong slightly) was the first try of mine when I tried to do it. Then when it didn't work I started to search for another solution. Well, perhaps I made a slight mistake then or was too sleepy then. Thank you!